# Running a Concourse-Task with an registry-image resource

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-task

I am using Concourse-CI in combination with a private Docker registry and everything works fine. However, I want to run a task as an image I provide via the registry. To clarify: I don't want to run the image within the task, the task source should be my image. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find an example on here or on the Concourse-CI docs.

My resource:

```
resources:
- name: my-image
  type: registry-image
  source:
    repository: ((registry-url))/my-image
    username: ...
    password: ...
    ca_certs:
    - ((registry-cert))
```

So, if I'm correct, the `task/config/source` cannot take a resource but an `anonymous-resource` where I would provide a `docker.io` link.

I am very appreciative for some help. :)

Edit: OK, so my first mistake was to only look at the `Task` schema, I can configure an image (https://concourse-ci.org/jobs.html#schema.step.task-step.image) but when I do:

```
- task: test
  image: my-image
  config:
    platform: linux
    inputs:
    run:
      ...
```

I get this error: `find or create container on worker 4c38517c9713: no image plugin configured`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
so the answer was to make the image privileged for some reason...

Comment: can you elaborate please? Examples etc would help future users looking at this .. and likely your future self too.